# how to I modify the inventory_hostname when using the aws_ec2 plugin?

Tags: ansible

I have an ec2 tag 'Name' on my hosts in AWS. I need to append a suffix to the hostname in my inventory. I'm essentially trying to do this:

```
plugin: aws_ec2
strict: False
hostnames: '"tag:Name" + ".suffix.com"'
```

as soon as I do anything resembling Jinja in my inventory plugin yaml file, `ansible-inventory` stops parsing the file as YAML and I get errors.

previously, when using the aws_ec2.py script for inventory, I could to something like:

```
destination_format: "{0}.suffix.com"
destination_format_tags: "Name"
```

I'd much rather use the plugin because it has nice features that the old, crusty aws_ec2.py script does not.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

A [change](https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/pull/826) in v3.3.0 of the Ansible Amazon AWS collection made it possible to use literal strings in the `hostnames` parameter -- previously the only accepted values were valid [DescribeInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html) filters.

This snippet will set `inventory_hostname` to the value of the instances' `Name` tag with `.example.com` appended:

```
hostnames:
  - name: .example.com
    separator: ''
    prefix: tag:Name
```